# How to write metachars within the pandas DatFarame in column's names

Tags: python, pandas

I have CSV file So, when parsing this file with pandas with `ISO-8859-1` encoding. However i'm just trying to create a DataFrame `df_cols` to print only selected columns but it giving the error on execution as it has metachars like `/` `'` (example `'Card Holder's Name', 'CVV/CVV2'`) hence fails to get the output.

```
#!/grid/common/pkgs/python/v3.6.1/bin/python3
##### Pandas Display Setting for the complete output on the terminal ####
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.height', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', True)

df_list = pd.read_csv('/docs/Credit_Card.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
df_cols = df_list[['Card Type Full Name', 'Issuing Bank', 'Card Number', 'Card Holder's Name', 'CVV/CVV2', 'Issue Date', 'Expiry Date','Credit Limit']]
print(df_cols)
```

Comment: what is the purpose of df_cols?

Comment: have you tried escaping with `\\` ? ie 'Card Holder\'s Name'

Comment: @d_kennetz,  df_cols are Just the selected columns which i want to see out of 100's cols So, just  needed the selected ones only.

Comment: @ChrisA, no chris, what exactly the syntax you refering.

Comment: try `df_cols = df_list[['Card Type Full Name', 'Issuing Bank', 'Card Number', 'Card Holder\'s Name', 'CVV/CVV2', 'Issue Date', 'Expiry Date','Credit Limit']]`

Comment: @ChrisA, let me try that.

Comment: @ChrisA you can do that in `pd.read_csv` you don't need a second df to do this. just do `pd.read_csv('/docs/Credit_card.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1', usecols=[0,1,2,3,4,5])`. Basically what I am saying is to use the column's positional value rather than string value to import the data.

Comment: @d_kennetz, but we don't have the column's positional value in a sequence hence picking them randomly but the trick is nice.. First we need to determine the column position in this way.

Comment: if you are uncertain of position, then use the escape character method although you still do not need to create 2 dataframes. Read in the csv by just selecting the specific columns you'd like. Don't read in the whole csv then select the columns. You are using 20X the memory by doing that if you are selecting 5/6 columns out of 100.

Comment: @d_kennetz, so you mean rather i should use  `pd.read_csv('/docs/Credit_card.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1', usecols=['Card Type Full Name', 'Issuing Bank', 'Card Number'])` to avoid memory hog.

Comment: thnx guys, both the answers provided by Chris & Pawel are working but the dilemma is which to choose as an answer as we need to check which is better in terms of  usage and advantage though i have upvoted both the answers.

Comment: @pygo sorry I’m on mobile or if write an answer. That second line of code df_cols is redundant as you could import all the columns you need in the read_csv command. You don’t not need to load a second DF into memory just to select certain columns. Instead just read in only the columns you want initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by d_kennetz , we can directly read the columns based on names or index position on the DataFrame `df_list` itself which will reduce the time and resource utilization( memory consumption) to read the whole CSV.

As mentioned there are two way to read the columns first based on names where we need to be extra careful about special/metachars whereas the second method based on the index position we don't need to care about this which is slightly more useful to avoid this glitch.

```
df_list = pd.read_csv('/docs/Credit_Card.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1',usecols=['Card Type Full Name', 'Issuing Bank', 'Card Number', 'Card Holder\'s Name', 'CVV/CVV2', 'Issue Date', 'Expiry Date','Credit Limit'])
```

OR

```
df_list = pd.read_csv('/docs/Credit_Card.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1',usecols=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10])
```

Answer (score 1):

try put column name in three quotation mark

```
"""Card Holder's Name"""
```

Comment: @ Pawel, let me try , i think  we can use double or single quotation mark both will act same?

Comment: Yes, you could.

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping the single quote character with `\`

```
df_cols = df_list[['Card Type Full Name', 'Issuing Bank', 'Card Number', 'Card Holder\'s Name', 'CVV/CVV2', 'Issue Date', 'Expiry Date','Credit Limit']]
```